# How to merge two different querysets with one common field in to one in django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 Querysets `Sales_order` and `Proc_order`. The only common field in both is the `product_id`. I want to merge both these query sets to one with all fields.

`sales_order` has fields `product_id`,`sales_qty`,`sales_price`.

`proc_order` has fields `product_id`, `proc_qty`, `proc_price`. I want to merge both these to get a queryset which looks like.

`combined_report` which has fields `product_id`,`sales_qty`,``` sales_price``proc_qty ```, `proc_price`.

My final aim is to calculate the difference between the number of products.

I'm using Django 2.1

Comment: Please show your model definitions. Django ORM is about field types, not just suggestive field names. Without them, you cannot expect precise answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way to capture all the values.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


subquery_qs = proc_order_qs.filter(product_id=OuterRef('product_id')

combined_qs = sales_order_qs.annotate(
    proc_qty = Cast(Subquery(subquery_qs.values('proc_qty')[:1]), output_field=FloatField()),
    proc_price = Cast(Subquery(subquery_qs.values('proc_price')[:1]), output_field=FloatField()))
```

And then you can get all the values in `combined_qs`

```
combined_qs.values('product_id','sales_qty','sales_price','proc_qty', 'proc_price')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error.  

raise FieldError('Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.')
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.

Comment: Updated answer for the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do something like this:
views.py

```
from itertools import chain


def yourview(request):
    Sales_order = ....
    Proc_order = ....
    combined_report = chain(Sales_order,Proc_order)
```